# Putting a random selection array print into a loop

Tags: arrays, loops, random

the following code is for a game, trying to put the random
unsure on how to insert a loop for the choice part of the code which selects random letters from each line of array within the array

```
#Boggle arrayception



DICE = [
["A", "A", "E", "E", "G", "N"],
["A", "B", "B", "J", "O", "O"],
["A", "C", "H", "O", "P", "S"],
["A", "F", "F", "K", "P", "S"],
["A", "O", "O", "T", "T", "W"],
["C", "I", "M", "O", "T", "V"],
["D", "E", "I", "L", "R", "X"],
["H", "L", "N", "N", "R", "Z"],
["D", "I", "S", "T", "T", "Y"],
["E", "E", "G", "H", "N", "W"],
["E", "E", "I", "N", "S", "U"],
["E", "H", "R", "T", "V", "W"],
["E", "I", "O", "S", "S", "T"],
["E", "L", "R", "T", "T", "Y"],
["H", "A", "E", "E", "G", "N"],
["A", "I", "M", "N", "Q", "U"]]




from random import choice
print choice(DICE[0])
print choice(DICE[1])
print choice(DICE[2])
print choice(DICE[3])
print choice(DICE[4])
print choice(DICE[5])
print choice(DICE[6])
print choice(DICE[7])
print choice(DICE[8])
print choice(DICE[9])
print choice(DICE[10])
print choice(DICE[11])
print choice(DICE[12])
print choice(DICE[13])
print choice(DICE[14])
print choice(DICE[15])
```

Comment: What language is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is python you could try:

```
for d in DICE:
    print choice(d)
```